# Do Pakistani citizens need a Hong Kong transit visa if their stay in the airport is only 4 hours?

Tags: visas, transit, hong-kong

I am travelling from Nanjing to Helsinki, Finland, transiting through Hong Kong, flying on Hong Kong Airlines and Finnair. I am a Pakistani national holding Chinese and Schengen visas. I have a gap between the flights of about 4 hours, meaning I will stay in Hong Kong airport for 4 hours. Do I need any kind of transit visa? And if yes, then how do I to apply?

Answer (score 4):

You [need](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html) to apply for a [transit visa](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit_transit.html). This can be done [online](https://www.gov.hk/en/nonresidents/visarequire/visasentrypermits/applyvisit_transit.htm).

Pakistan has the ※ mark, which reads:

> All nationals (except holders of Diplomatic and Official passports) are required to hold a valid visa for the HKSAR for whatever purpose **(including those who are in transit and remain on the airside)**. Holders of Diplomatic and Official passports may visit the HKSAR visa-free for a stay not exceeding 30 days.

(**Emphasis** mine).